# TFS and Tridion Integration

Tags: 2011

Is there a way to integrate Tridion with TFS which helps in the build process to get the latest components , Pages and Component Templates to be checked in to TFS by some process.

Comment: Other than using WebDav, I can't think of any way that would work out-of-the-box. With some creative CoreService work this can be done - or with Content Porter automation and few smartly built Search Folders.

Comment: Are you referring to Team Foundation Server?

Answer (score 6):

My answer would begin by asking: Why do you want to use TFS to control SDL Tridion items?
If what you want to achieve is to control a Tridion Content Manager project you can take a look at SDL Quatron.

In case you are really interested in using TFS to control SDL Tridion items there is a set of tools and frameworks that can help. It is called [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/).

With TFS Integration Platform you can develop your own TFS adapter so that you can synchronize items between TFS and an external product (SDL Tridion in this case). There are some POC adapters for Sharepoint and Biztalk.

Check this post to get some more information: [TFS Adapters Overview](http://www.sadev.co.za/content/how-create-adapter-tfs-integration-platform-part-iii-overview-adapters?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20Sadev%20%28SADev.co.za%29).

Comment: I would not consider a TFS Integration Platform solution unless it was the very last option. Its really not worth it. Takes about 6 weeks to just get to grips with the API and churn out a basic adapter.

Answer (score 4):

I'd only consider integrating with TFS for Tridion-related code such as C# TBB assemblies, external workflow activities, or the event system. As an example, Jonathan Whiteside's description of Building Block's [continuous build process for C# TBBs](http://www.building-blocks.com/thinking/continuous-integration-with-sdl-tridion-modular-templates/) (using CC.NET then later TeamCity).

Even with this type of build process, you'd typical move developer-related items up environments (starting from dev up to production CMS), but content and pages *down*.

See [SDL Live Content](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_ContentPorter_2013/concept_73AE38095D5E470E8163CE63D0DF2264) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion)) for typical content transfer scenarios using Content Porter.

If looking to do more, be sure to account for:

- **BluePrinting** including dependencies, shared items, and localization (if "checking in" a template, you'd likely want its schema)
- **Authorization** including handling any content and pages developers don't "own"
- **Managed references** (saving and treating a Tridion item like a flat file is only useful to the same CMS environment)
- **Moves, renames, and deletions** of items, paths, as well as schema fields

Answer (score 2):

As you know, Tridion has its own versioning system. It is actually very meaningful for non-system items, i.e. Components and Pages.  So keeping this stuff in Tridion, not TFS, makes a lot of sense.  System items, e.g. TBBs, Event System code and Workflow have their place in TFS.  The only other item that falls in between is Schema, which may be dependent on Categories/Keywords, so storing schema XSD files in TFS may not be worthwhile (Dominic Cronin raised a question on this a while back on StackOverflow).  So the easiest thing is to stick to the usual process of keeping Content related items in Tridion (Pages and Components and Keywords), and System items in TFS.  TBBs via TcmUploadAssembly and Workflow and Event DLLs via the usual application deployment methods.

I think for what you're trying to do, the best thing may be to integrate TFS with Content Porter.  CP can be run from the command line, therefore you can make a script with an "export" command that creates a zip file of your Tridion items and checks them into TFS.  By the same means you can make script that imports items into Tridion from TFS.